# a button to link AND submit a form in react.js. I've tried href, link, to, onClick, history.push, and I am looking for another idea

Tags: reactjs, button, hyperlink, onclick, submit

I have tried to add Link, to, href, a href, onClick to add a link to the button. This is the front end to a book-index project. I also tried history.push, I the button is in a form to submit. I want the button then take it to a landing page saying "book added" If I add a Link to the button, it will link to the page then the submit doesn't load. I can get one to work or the other, but not both. The code I have is for the submit.
this is in a react.js class component

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div style={{padding:"10px"}}>
                <h1 style={{textAlign:"center"}}>Add a Book Below</h1> 
                {console.log("state", this.state)}

                <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="add-title" style={{textAlign:"center", paddingBottom:"10px"}}>
                        <label>Title:</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name = "title"
                                value={this.state.title}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />
                    </div>

                    <div className="add-author" style={{textAlign:"center", paddingBottom:"10px"}}>
                        <label>Author:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name = "author"
                            value={this.state.author}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                    </div>

                    <div className="submit" style={{textAlign:"center", paddingBottom:'100px'}}>

                       <button

                        type="submit" 
                        value="submit"

                        >Submit</button>
```

Comment: let me know if you need more of the code. Thanks.

Comment: I am confused and really do not understand what you want